# what is the correct format of regex given to the serach method of the re module?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read the output of the  `~$ ifconfig` command with a python script and grab the private IP-address.
this is for example the output of the command:

```
~$ ifconfig  
vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.216.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.216.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 213  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.37.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.37.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 213  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

so then if we go ahead and direct the output of the command to this python script...

```
import sys
import re

data = sys.stdin.read()
x = re.search(r"^vmnet[2-9]:\s?.*(\n.*){7}", data)
print(x)
```

```
~$ ifconfig | ./script.py
```

the output should be:

```
vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.37.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.37.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 213  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but instead i simply get:

```
None
```

Comment: What is in `txt`?

Comment: You've put your data in `data` and matched `txt`!

Comment: that was just a typo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import sys
import re

data = sys.stdin.read()
match = re.search( r'(?m)^vmnet[2-9]:\s?.*(\n.*){7}', data )
if match:
    print match.group()
```

The typo has already been mentioned in the comments.

You also had to use `group()` or `group(0)` with the `Match` object returned by `.search()`.

Also note the `(?m)` flag.